# Finding certain VALUES of indices in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors which are of same length M and N. The values of the vectors represent the indices of another matrix A so that the corresponding indices in vector M and N make index pairs of A.

For example I have matrices

`M=[1 2 3 4]` and `N=[5 6 7 8]`

I would like to find the values of specific indices in matrix A and store them to another vector I, like this:

```
I = [A(1,5) A(2,6) A(3,7) A(4,8)]
```

How could this be done?

Comment: this has been here asked many times before. Can someone help me find duplicates?

Comment: @Amro You are right, there are several questions with similar problem. However, there is no one exact duplicate that can be found with simple search.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert them to [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/Matrix-Indexing-in-MATLAB/matrix.html) using `sub2ind` and then use those linear indices to index `A`:

```
ind = sub2ind(size(A), M(:), N(:));
I = A(ind);
```

Note I've gone `M(:)` as this guarantees that `M` will be a column vector